# Can we use pointer in union?

Tags: c, embedded, unions

If no why? Uses of union over structure??

Answer (score 14):

You can use any data type in a union, there's no restriction.

As to the use of unions over structures, structures lay out their data sequentially in memory. This mean all their sub-components are separate.

Unions, on the other hand, use the same memory for all their sub-components so only one can exist at a time.

For example:

```
                                 ┌─────┬─────┐
struct { int a; float b }  gives │  a  │  b  │
                                 └─────┴─────┘
                                    ▲     ▲
                                    │     │
                 memory location:  150   154
                                    │
                                    ▼
                                 ┌─────┐
union { int a; float b }  gives  │  a  │
                                 │  b  │
                                 └─────┘
```

Structures are used where an "object" is composed of other objects, like a point object consisting of two integers, those being the x and y coordinates:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;           // x and y are separate
    int y;
} tPoint;
```

Unions are typically used in situation where an object can be one of many things but only one at a time, such as a type-less storage system:

```
typedef enum { STR, INT } tType;
typedef struct {
    tType typ;          // typ is separate.
    union {
        int ival;       // ival and sval occupy same memory.
        char *sval;
    }
} tVal;
```

They are useful for saving memory although that tends to be less and less of a concern nowadays (other than in low-level work like embedded systems) so you don't see a lot of it.

Comment: Unions are not for saving memory: they express a *sum type*, ie. a type which holds eg. *either* a float *or* an int. Unions are difficult to use, and quite limited. Please consider using `boost::variant` instead.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree with pretty much all of that, @Alexandre :-) They _are_ (even now) useful for saving memory especially in the small-embedded world. They're not difficult to use if you understand the underlying layout (including implementation-defined foibles) and until someone ports boost to C (check the tags), the variant type isn't going to be much use :-)

Comment: I forgot 1) that it was C 2) that people need to be close to the hardware sometimes. Nevertheless, my point is that unions (in C++) should not be used to represent sum types.

Comment: @AlexandreC. What's wrong with tagged unions again? Your supporting arguments seem questionable and have been well rebutted. Do you offer any further justification? I consider "limitation" irrelevant because the construct (tagged union) is amply equipped for the job, and "difficulty" is clearly subjective. Ironically, I consider maintaining flow while waiting for `boost` to be vastly more difficult and time consuming than simply thinking clearly about what I am programming.

Comment: How can I access the sval member in this struct? Will it be like this:  `struct tVal tval; tval->sval;` or we need to specify indentifier for union and use that for accessing union members like `tval.uval->sval;`

Comment: @KamalPandey: With that definition, it's not a pointer, so it would actually be `tval.sval`. And that only works if there is the one unnamed union. If you have named unions like `union { int ival; char * sval} name;`, I think you need to specify that: `tval.name.sval`.

Comment: @KamalPandey: if it *is* a pointer, you can use what you originally had. So (non-pointer): `tVal tval; use(tval.sval);` or (pointer) `tVal *tvalp = some_tval_pointer(); use(tvalp->sval);`. Even though `a->b` is syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`, only the truly sadistic use that latter form :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks for the response. So for derefrencing that sval pointer, should it be `*tval.sval` or `tval.*sval`.

Comment: @KamalPandey, there are a lot of possibilities, depending on what's a pointer and what is not. It may be better for you to ask an actual question so that more people get to respond.

Answer (score 4):

Well, according to ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 (the C99 standard):

> A union type describes an overlapping nonempty set of member objects, each of
>   which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct type.

In short, the memory space of union members overlaps, and the names you give to union members allow you to read memory at that location in size. Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t a;
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t c;
        uint8_t d;
    };
    uint32_t x;
} somenewtype;

typedef union
{
    uint32_t* p;
    uint8_t* q;
} somepointer;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    uint32_t r;
    uint8_t s;
    somenewtype z;
    somepointer p;
    r = 0x11223344; s = 0x11;
    z.x = 0x11223344;
    p.p = &r;
    p.q = &s;
    printf("%x%x%x%x\n", z.d, z.c, z.b, z.a);
    printf("%x %x\n", *(p.p), *(p.q));
}
```

In the first printf, what we're doing is printing out 8-bit parts of the 32-bit integer. Hoping of course for no padding in that anonymous struct.

In the second printf? I had to step through using gdb to understand, but I did:

```
p.p = (uint32_t *) 0x7fffffffde5c;
p.q =  (uint8_t *) 0x7fffffffde5b "\021D3\"\021P\337\377\377\377\177";
p.p = (uint32_t *) 0x7fffffffde5b;
```

Well of course, pointers are all the same size, so assigning `p.q` overwrites the address of `p.p`. I suspect strongly that de-referencing the address of the 32-bit integer to an 8-bit pointer is printing "whatever is at that location + 32 bits in size" which co-incidentally for me happens to be `22334411`. But I suspect, at that point, the behaviour is undefined.

Anyway, the point of that little exercise was to show you that:

- unions can be used to access the same memory location through a different "type" modifier.
- You have to be careful what you do and understand the underlying type you're using. If you're going to use pointers, beware their modification as you might start pointing to who knows what.

I should point out I can see the practical use for `somenewtype` but not for `somepointer` - that was a contrived example I was pretty sure would break.